# How to add NEW Workspaces with Python, not just append from user preferences, or switch to a workspace?

Tags: python, workspaces

I am aware of questions of similarity such as this: [Changing workspace with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179505/changing-workspace-with-python), and this one on Blender Artists.org https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-create-new-layout-workspace/1380035, however, neither of these are what I amlooking for.

What I am trying to accomplish is changing the default workspace layout order with one click.

I already have the button set up, but I still need to add the workspaces to the def execute command.

I'm trying to go from this default workspace setup

[image: Default Workspace Setup]

to this setup:

[image]

The addition of the Assets Workspace is why I can't just use the Append_Activate command, as it's a custom workspace, and I want this to be useable as soon as you open Blender and activate the add-on.

The Assets workspace is simply a duplicate of the Layout workspace, but with the Timeline switched to the Asset Browser.

I would really appreciate if someone could help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you really need python for this? You can already add an Assets workspace from the menubar dropdown which appears when you click the '+' at the R/H end of the Workspace entries (under the General entry). You can then use File > Defaults > Save Startup File to make it permanent.

Comment: Blender doesn't actually have an Assets workspace. BforArtists does. I'm trying to use Python to automate the process of setting up the workspaces so I don't have to go through the 36 clicks needed every time I either get a new Blender version and don't import my old settings (Which is actually slower than me doing it manually anyway), or if I need to revert to factory settings for whatever reason.

Comment: Blender versions from 3.3 certainly do have an Assets workspace! As I said, you can select the layout with the '+' button menu and add it it from the General > Assets menu there. You can then move it along the toolbar by right-clicking on the entry, selecting Reorder to Front, and then do the same for the Layout entry to get the order you want.

Comment: O.o I never thought the Blender team would actually add an Assets workspace. Though that still doesn't help if you happen to be using 3.3 or earlier, but this is at least a good reason for me to finally upgrade to 3.4.

Comment: 3.3 (LTS) certainly has it and I'm pretty sure that 3.2 had it too although I don't have that version installed now.